# How to extend the VLAN defined in the Ethernet network into the WiFi network?

Tags: networking, wifi, vlan

How to extend the VLAN that you have defined in the Ethernet network into the WiFi network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 options:

You need access-points with support for 802.11q.
This is an extension on regular WIFI that adds VLAN support to Wifi.
Be warned: These things are very expensive.

The other solution is to use access-points that can broadcast multiple WIFI LAN's and assign each of these WIFI LAN's to a different VLAN.
This is easier to setup and less expensive too.

And last, but not least:
Separate access-points in each VLAN. This is cheapest as it can be done with any access-point. (AP isn't VLAN aware at all in this case.)